# Error `No protocol specified` when running from remote machine via ssh

Tags: ssh, x11

I have a script, simply to run my Graphical (GUI) Application, as below.

```
#cat gui.sh
#!/bin/bash 
./gui -display 127.0.0.1:0.0
```

When I run it from local machine (`./gui.sh`) it runs perfectly fine. But when I am trying to run it from remote machine via ssh, I got following error.

```
[root@localhost]# ssh -f 192.168.3.77 "cd /root/Desktop/GUI/ && "./gui.sh""   
No protocol specified  
gdm: cannot connect to X server 192.168.3.77:0.0   
[root@localhost]#
```

I don't know, which protocol it is asking or am I missing anything? I tried directly by starting the application, without script [`ssh -f 192.168.3.77 "cd /root/Desktop/GUI/ && "./gui""`], but the result is same. I have tried various combinations like `ssh -Y`, `ssh -fY` and more but the result is same!
Secondly for my application, there is a must condition that, we have to first go into the directory where the program is located.
Any Solutions?

Answer (score 12):

[This](http://youtu.be/ue7D6K9cFys)  video explains how to solve the error step by step. If you don't wan't to watch then follow the text below:

The No protocol specified error indicates that "the user doesn't know how to launch a GUI application" and the "user doesn't have permissions to launch a GUI application". In the video the GUI application is `dbca`.

The key piece of this video is in running the command `xhost +` which grants the user permissions to remotely display a GUI from a remote system, to the local system.

Comment: `xhost +` will give access to anybody to connect to your display. I would recommend `xhost +local:[hostname or ip]`

Comment: This and [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/xlib-connection-to-0-0-refused-by-server-xlib-no-protocol-specified-152556/#post791278) is what fixed the error for me. +1

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of the option `-display 127.0.0.1:0.0` depends on that `gui` program, but it's highly likely that it means “display on the X display 127.0.0.1:0.0”. This is the first local X display, accessed over TCP. This is almost certainly wrong for two reasons. First, the local X display should be `:0`, not `127.0.0.1:0`, because including an IP address causes the traffic to go through TCP instead of local access. Going through TCP may not work depending on whether the X server accepts TCP connections. Even if it does, you lose the optimizations that local displays have.

The display to use is normally indicated by the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and that variable tends to be set correctly automatically. (Usually, if `DISPLAY` has the wrong value, it's because you've been messing with it. The main exception is use of `screen` or `tmux`.)

Your program probably does look up the value of the `DISPLAY` environment variable, because that tends to happen automatically with xlib calls. So you should just call `./gui`, your script doesn't do anything useful. If your program insists on the `-display` argument, make it use the environment variable:

```
./gui -display "$DISPLAY"
```

Answer (score 5):

`ssh -Y` and `ssh -X` should be a good start but did you forward your X server as well?

```
$ grep X /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
```

otherwise it won't work.

Another thing to check is the DISPLAY variable it should show something like this:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
$ localhost:10.0
```

this was run after `ssh -Y`. The same variable is empty if I ssh without `-Y` or `-X`.

For differences between `-X` and `-Y` read the man page of ssh.

Answer (score 5):

Debian Jessie, add also:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/.Xauthority
```

Comment: `xhost +` fixed my problem (on the client side)

Comment: That helped, thank you! My XAUTHORITY was `/tmp/xauth-1000-_0` but after starting two additional X sessions that file had disappeared - only the third one remained. To fix the problem for all windows I restored it with: `ln -s ~/.Xauthority /tmp/xauth-1000-_0`

Answer (score 2):

I was hit by same issue I resolved it by changing the DISPLAY environment variable from:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

to

```
export DISPLAY=:10
```